# Как получить урл ссылки в переменную

Tags: javascript

Есть HTML код.

```
<ul class="br">
  <li class="bj">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="u">
            <a href="/1">1</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </li>
  <li class="bj">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="u">
            <a href="/1">1</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Как получить урл например 1 ссылки в переменную?
Пробовал сделать так

```
elementList = window.content.document.querySelectorAll('.br .u a')[0].innerHTML;
alert(elementList);
```

Не получается.

И еще было бы не плохо посчитать их все и занести в переменную. Но это уже вторично, главное урл определенной ссылки получить.

Считать пробовал так, но не чего не получается.

```
elementList = window.content.document.querySelectorAll('.br .u a'); 
alert(elementList.length);
```

Comment: jquery не используешь?

Comment: @Андрей нет, только чистый JavaScript

Comment: А кто сказал, что `ul>td` строятся в корректный DOM? Либо `ul>li`, либо нормальную таблицу дорисуй

Comment: @vp_arth дорисовал

Comment: Уё) Так-то тебе попроще будет элементы выбирать, наверное.

Comment: Можно же было в одну строку одной таблицы...

Comment: @vp_arth это такой код в ФБ, это я в нем свои группы хочу посчитать.

Comment: И `document.querySelectorAll('.br .u a')[0].getAttribute('href')` не работает?

Comment: @vp_arth работает, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот код где я сохранил в массив `array_tag_a` все `url` из списка `ul.br`:

```js
var matches = document.querySelectorAll("ul.br a");
var array_tag_a = []; 
for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
  array_tag_a.push (matches[i].getAttribute('href'));
}
console.log(array_tag_a);
```

```html
<ul class="br">
  <li class="bj">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="u">
            <a href="/1">1</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </li>
  <li class="bj">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="u">
            <a href="/1">1</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо, все пашет.

Comment: @Анатолий Не стоит благодарности)